# Leaflet polyline not moving on drag/zoom

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, polyline

I'm using leaflet with custom CRS.Simple projection. If I draw a polyline at the page Load it is more or less drawn ok (Although much more accurate in firefox than in chrome) but if I drag the map the polyline remains in the same place of the browser window, so then appears shifted respect of the background map.

Example: 
Initial load
[image: initial load]

[image: After drag the map, the map moves but the polyline remains in the same place]

After drag the map, the map moves but the polyline remains in the same place

To add the polyline I'm converting the coordinates to the CRS.Simple projection. I don't think there is a problem here as every other map marker or text appears correctly

```
.....
//initialize leaflet map
map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
    minZoom: mapMinZoom,
    zoomControl: false,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple  //simple coordinates system
}).setView([0, 0], mapMaxZoom);

//set the bounds of the map to the current dimension
var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
    map.unproject([0, mapHeight], mapMaxZoom),
    map.unproject([mapWidth, 0], mapMaxZoom)
 );

//load the tiles       
map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
L.tileLayer(mapData.info.tiles+'/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    minZoom: mapMinZoom,
    maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
    bounds: mapBounds,
    attribution: '',
    noWrap: true,
    continuousWorld: true    
}).addTo(map);
.....
var pointList = [getMapCoordinates(1750,1750),
                getMapCoordinates(1520,1764),
                getMapCoordinates(1300,1560),
                getMapCoordinates(1132,1258),
                 getMapCoordinates(1132,1060),
                 getMapCoordinates(926,960)];

polyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.5,
    smoothFactor: 1
});
polyline.addTo(map);
....

function getMapCoordinates(px,py)
{
    //as we use simple system, transform the point (based on pixel) on map coordinates that leaflet understand
    return map.unproject([px, py], map.getMaxZoom());
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or is it a bug? Any workaround would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the problem was in stable version (0.7.3) Using dev version (1.0-dev) works ok and even solves the problem with the different browser drawing